# Drools conditions in the consequence: Benefits or Costs?

Tags: drools

I am new to drools with a background in java. I have gained a basic undertanding of drools.

I have inherited a large drools project which works, but appears to be hacked together. Most of the rules have many and nested IF and ELSE statements in the "then" (consequence?). I believe this is bad practice. Can anyone confirm, references to materials on the internet would be useful.

Also what are the benefits in correcting this other than readability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to dig for references but the general consent among rule programmers is that decisions should be made on the LHS/condition part of a rule. The simple reason is that the Engine is dedicated to the process of "many pattern/many object" pattern match problem. Even if there is one final condition where some action is necessary for both, true and false, Drools syntax provides a good solution, i.e., extending a rule twice, once with the positive and once with the negative condition.

That said, an *occasional* conditional statement may be tolerated or even fine, e.g., when it merely distinguishes between details in the works of the RHS/consequence part of a rule. But "many and nested" sounds rather bad - but maybe this "distinction of the details" does require such logic.

As for the benefits: nobody can tell without inspection, and then it'll need an experienced judge.

Since you've asked for references: http://www.redhat.com/rhecm/rest-rhecm/jcr/repository/collaboration/sites%20content/live/redhat/web-cabinet/home/resourcelibrary/whitepapers/brms-design-patterns/rh:pdfFile.pdf

Comment: Where I have seen if/then working reasonably well is when the RHS is making conditional calls to a database. This avoids database calls in the LHS (i.e. via en eval). However, in almost all (maybe all?) cases I have seen, conditionality in the RHS was better replaced by a refactoring to 2 or more separate rules. Note that earlier versions of Drools didn't support extending a rule, so conditional logic in the RHS may not have been a bad decision at the time the rules were written, as it could avoid repeating multiple almost identical pattern matches in multiple rules.

Comment: Shame I can't persuade my boss this is the correct way of coding it and will make things far easier.

Answer (score 1):

One non-readability reasoning for putting as much evaluation in the LHS as possible is performance. For one thing it avoids unnecessary rule activations, but it also makes significant performance gains through caching the results of each of the matches, thereby avoiding re-evaluation.

This caching is not available to conditional logic on the RHS.

This is one reason why you invoke update/modify on a fact when you change it. This effectively instructs the engine that previously cached LHS evaluations relating to that fact can be discarded.

Answer (score -2):

Nested `"if/else"` statements are generally not bad practice as logical operations are not stressful on the CPU, nor does it require copious amounts of memory.

I'm not a Drools programmer, but I imagine, since you alluded it to Java, it's an obj-oriented high-level prgramming language.

Howver, in the event that multiple `if` statements can be combined, it's recommended to do so for clear, clean coding, not necessarily performance.

Comment: This answer is based on assumptions. As you say, you are not a drools programmer. I completeley understand how ifs, if elses and nested if elses work. I am talking about in the context of a consequence in drools.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be given on assumptions. Drools is a Production Rule system, which makes the answer rather out-of-bounds.

Comment: My appologies. In my defense, you asked for the "consequences" of nested if/else statements. I was only trying to help.

Comment: @Goodies I didnt down vote you. Also its not the consequences of the statments. its using the statements in the consequence. I reccommend deleting your answer before any more downvotes. Dont let that down vote put you off. Keep answering! - but stick to subjects you fully know about.